# SQL Server data scripts for the first 1000 or so records

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, localhost, remote-server

I am trying to replicate (not entire data) a remote SQL Server to my local host. I have generated the scripts for schema creation from the remote server and got the script ran successfully on `localhost`. Now, I want to get some data into these tables. The problem is, remote server has millions of records and I don't want all of them dumped on to my tables. I just want, say a max of 1000 records per table. How do I achieve this, is this something possible at all? I am using SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Do any of the tables have foreign key constraints?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1000 ....

Comment: I have a total of 596 tables and there is atleast one foreign key reference in each of these tables :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, link your local server to the remote server, using code like this:

```
 EXEC sp_addlinkedServer N'remoteSqlServer\Instance', N'SQL Server'
 EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'remoteSqlServer\Instance', @useself = 'FALSE', @rmtuser = N'user', @rmtpassword = N'password'
```

Be sure to substitute your remote SQL Server instance name, user, and password in the above script.

Then run a statement like this... you can specify an ORDER BY if you want to, say, grab just the most recent records, or by some other criteria:

```
INSERT INTO [LocalTableName]
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [remoteSqlServer\Instance].[DatabaseName].[schema].[RemoteTableName]
```

Again, substitute the server instance, database name, schema (probably 'dbo'), and table names.

If your table contains any IDENTITY or TIMESTAMP columns, you'll have to actually list out all the columns EXCEPT those columns in the INSERT statement, and instead of the * in the SELECT statement.

I hope this helps.